# Can't Install Curb - Having problems with native extensions.

Tags: ruby, curl, debian, rvm, curb

I'm trying to install the curb gem on my Debian machine but I'm having a hard time building the gem with native extensions. I'm using RVM.

Just a list of things I'm using:

- debian
- bundler
- rvm
- ruby-1.9.2-p180
- curb

I'm told I have to install the following packages and I've done so:

`sudo apt-get install libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4-openssl-dev`

When I go ahead and do as such:

gem install curb

`Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing curb:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`

```
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby extconf.rb
```

checking for curl-config... yes
checking for curlinfo_redirect_time... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
    --with-curl-dir
    --with-curl-include
    --without-curl-include=${curl-dir}/include
    --with-curl-lib
    --without-curl-lib=${curl-dir}/lib
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:368:in `try_do': The complier failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:446:in`try_compile'
    from extconf.rb:51:in `block in have_constant'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:693:in`block in checking_for'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in`open'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block in postpone'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in`open'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:276:in `postpone'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:692:in`checking_for'
    from extconf.rb:43:in `have_constant'
    from extconf.rb:60:in`'

I don't any way around this, any ideas?

Thanks buds.

Comment: I'm getting similar problems on OSX installing curb with rvm against a libcurl that previously worked with my own installation of ruby and curb. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Having the same problem on Mountain Lion (OSX 10.8). I have two installations of it, works on the iMac fails on the MBA, I can't see any differences yet.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

On a Debian Squeeze, I've managed to install `curb` with `libcurl4-openssl-dev` installed before.

It may also work with `libcurl4-gnutls-dev`, but I've no tested.

Comment: Also, don't forget to sudo gem install curb after you've installed libcurl4-openssl-dev

Comment: installing `libcurl4-gnutls-dev` instead of `libcurl3-gnutls-dev` worked for me.

Comment: installing libcurl4-gnutls-dev worked for me on Ubuntu 11.04. that package was not listed in Ubuntu dependencies in Curb readme.

Comment: What worked for me was libcurl14-openssl-dev after doing an apt-get update  (This is for 12.04)

Answer (score 5):

You probably need to install curl-devel package.

yum install curl-devel

Comment: This worked for me. I'm starting to hate Yum.. every instruction I read on the web tells me to do apt-get. ARGH!

Answer (score 2):

openssl used to work for me, but now libcurl4-gnutls-dev is all that works for me...